# how can I pass request API response with express to react?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, google-analytics-api

I have the following server-side set-up:

```
router.get(
    "/auth/google",
    passport.authenticate("google", { scope: ['Profile','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'] })
);

router.get(
    "/auth/google/callback",
    passport.authenticate("google", { failureRedirect: "/error", session: false }),
    function(req, res) {
        var token = req.user.token;
        res.redirect("/getData?token=" + token);
    }
);

router.get('/getData', function(req, res) {
    var token = req.query.token;
request('https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts?access_token=' + token,  
function (error, response, body) {
          let views = []
   JSON.parse(body).items.forEach(view => {
            views.push({
              name: view.webPropertyId + ' - ' + view.name + ' (' + view.websiteUrl + ')'
            })
          })
res.send(views)
});
})
```

with the following client-side component:

```
     componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://localhost:5000/getData',
    {
          method: 'put',
          headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
      })
      .then(res => { 
        if (!res.ok) {
          throw res;
        }
        return res.json()
      }).then(data => {
        this.setState({loading: false, data});
      }).catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
        this.setState({loading: false, error: true});
      });
  }
```

how do I'm supposed to configure express so I can fetch my back-end and pass the response from the API request on my front-end?

Right now I'm getting the following error `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: Have you actually spun up a web server listening on port 5000?  Is your express service throwing any errors?  If you put in a console print statement in the top of your route handler, does it get printed out?

Comment: yes so have two terminal opens. No error is throwing. The only error I have is on the  chrome console client-side which is the error I've mentioned in my question: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`. And yes token and request-response are printed out correctly in the server-side terminal console log. Do I'm answering your question?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try switching the put method to a get in your fetch params - method: 'GET'

Comment: when switching to get I got new errors: `GET http://localhost:5000/getData net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` and `TypeError: Failed to fetch` on the front-end and `Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined` on the back-end.

Comment: That means body.items is not defined.  It needs to be an iterable to call forEach on it.  What does body contain?

Comment: yes. body here is not defined `JSON.parse(body).items.forEach(view => {` and it is not defined because the react compornent is fetching `/getData'` without passing the token... does it make sense?

Comment: Right, that makes sense.  It's expecting token in the query string but it's not being passed.  My guess is that you don't want /getdata to be called by your client directly.  Judging by your set up, you hit whatever google service you need to authenticate with then google hits your /auth/google/callback route with the token which then redirects the client to /getData which returns the views.  I'm not sure what the exact specs are for the service you're using but google probably describes what you need to do in the docs.

Comment: If I were a gambling man, I'd guess the route you need your client to hit is /auth/google, but I'm really just guessing at this point.  You need somebody who knows google analytics api's auth policy so I added it as a tag to your question so they can chime in.

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with Google. This is the way I structuring my app. Like you said I shouldn't call the /getdata directly. But what should I call? what I want to do is running the auth process, running the request, getting the response and passing it to the front-end. Everything is kind of working however I need to find a way to pass the response from the request to the front-end.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200417/discussion-between-simon-breton-and-allen-more).

Comment: On your server side code, can you try throwing a console log on the response and error objects in your request's callback. I feel like your response object might have the body you need. If not, console logging the error object should give you a bit more detailed explanation of what's going wrong

Answer (score 1):

You need to send the information through JSON. That's `res.json(dataObject);`, which will be picked up by the second `.then` in the fetch call. You are currently trying to use `res.send()`.

Comment: got the same error as commented on in the other answer.